# How do I decode base64 encoded session data from Catalyst::Plugin::Session?

Tags: perl, base64, catalyst

I've inherited some code that uses these session modules that will encode some kind of obfuscated Base64 text to store in a table and decode it out, but there doesn't seem to be a way for me to actually get the data decoded correctly.

It seems to use [Catalyst::Plugin::Session](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Plugin::Session), but I've had no luck decoding it in any encoding or anything.

If I decode the data as it is now, I get back normal-looking text for Latin characters, but other things like basic numbers seem to be garbled. I've tried just about every character encoding with no success.

How do I decode the data stored by this module?

The actual usage in the code looks like this:

```
$user->update({ user_id => $user->id });
$c->session->{user_name} = $user->name;
```

Comment: The code of [CGI::Session::Serialize::Base64](https://metacpan.org/source/MJFS/Base64-Serializer_0.1/Base64.pm) looks pretty straight-forward. It uses MIME::Base64. Nothing special there. Can you provide example data?

Comment: Also, you tagged the question with _catalyst_ but you're talking about CGI::Session. Those two don't really mix well. Which one is it?

Comment: Oops, yeah, seems to use Catalyst::Plugin::Session, my bad.

Comment: You should really include some example data pulled from a serialized session, and maybe the part of your code that writes those. I don't see how that would take your serialization module

Answer (score 0):

Agh, found out my obfuscated string is actually the demonic way in which Perl stores hashes in string form, and the Catalyst modules seem to use [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) to do this, so using MIME::Base64 and Storable together was the solution, like so:

```
print thaw(decode_base64($my_stuff));
```